# Dynamically loop and scroll to div when clicked

Tags: jquery, html

When the user clicks the first paragraph class "targetgo" I want to scroll to the "size1"  class . Second paragraph with "size2" and so on . Here is the code. Is there any way to shorten the code cause I am going to write more than 25 things like this.

```
$(".targetgo").eq(0).click(function(){
        $("body").scrollTo(".size1",2000); 
  });
   $(".targetgo").eq(1).click(function(){
        $("body").scrollTo(".size2",2000); 
  });
   $(".targetgo").eq(2).click(function(){
        $("body").scrollTo(".size3",2000); 

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, why not?

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    $(".targetgo").eq(i).click(function(){
        $("body").scrollTo(".size"+(i+1),2000); 
    });
}
```

So increase `i` to get more cycles....

Comment: `$("body").scrollTo(".size"+(i+1),2000);`* ;o)

Comment: Tried this in my code but it scrolls to the last element

Comment: @Rem eh, give a fiddle please.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".targetgo").each(
    function(i,el) {
        $(el).on('click', function() {
            $("body").scrollTo(".size"+i,2000); 
        });
    }
);
```

if you don't know how many .targetgo there is, use $.each()

EDIT: not sure if i is base 0 or 1. +1 if needed.

Comment: No problem :D Thanks a lot, tried something similar but couldn't solve